# Why does new file created by touch have GID wheel?

Tags: macos, unix, high-sierra, filesystem

I have an account on macOS 10.13.2 (High Sierra) where `groups` returns this:

```
staff everyone localaccounts com.apple.sharepoint.group.2 
_lpoperator com.apple.sharepoint.group.1
```

Yet when I `touch` a new file I see [`wheel`](https://superuser.com/questions/191955/what-is-the-wheel-user-in-os-x), which is not in the list, as GID:

```
$ touch /var/tmp/hello
$ ls -l /var/tmp/hello
-rw-r--r--  1 account  wheel  0 Dec 24 18:36 /var/tmp/hello
```

What is going in here? (If this were, say, Debian I would have expected the new file to be owned by `account:account` instead of `account:wheel`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/var/tmp` has the sticky bit set:

```
pse@Mithos:~$ ll -d /var/tmp
drwxrwxrwt  5 root  wheel  170 Dec 24 16:17 /var/tmp/
```

so any files created in there inherit the group of the directory.

From `man sticky`:

> A directory whose `sticky bit' is set becomes an append-only directory, or, more accurately, a
>        directory in which the deletion of files is restricted.  A file in a sticky directory may only be
>        removed or renamed by a user if the user has write permission for the directory and the user is
>        the owner of the file, the owner of the directory, or the super-user.  This feature is usefully
>        applied to directories such as /tmp which must be publicly writable but should deny users the
>        license to arbitrarily delete or rename each others' files.
>
> Any user may create a sticky directory.  See chmod(1) for details about modifying file modes.